# Angular async pipe hangs on a promise

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, promise

this is a snippet of my template:

```
<div class="explanation">
 {{ foo() | async }}
</div>
```

this is the function:

```
  foo(): Promise<string> {
    return Promise.resolve('hello');
  }
```

This just hangs the browser. How come? what am i missing?

Comment: Did the same for me.

Comment: I think this scenario runs into side effects mentioned in doc. https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#avoid-side-effects If I change it to property, everything works fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-apa5om?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [**MDN on `Promise.resolve`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)

> Warning: Do not call Promise.resolve on a thenable that resolves to itself. This will cause infinite recursion as it tries to flatten what seems to be an infinitely nested promise.

**AND**

From [**Angular's Avoid side effects guideline**](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#avoid-side-effects):

> evaluation of a template expression should have no visible side effects. The expression language itself does its part to keep you safe. You can't assign a value to anything in a property binding expression nor use the increment and decrement operators.

Your implementation seems to do just that.

**Fix:**

As suggested by wannadream, assign the promise to a property and then use that property in the template along with the `async` pipe:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent  {
  foo: Promise<string>;

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.foo = Promise.resolve('hello'); 
  }
}
```

And in the template:

```
<div class="explanation">
  {{ foo | async }}
</div>
```

Comment: I dont understand how what i did is different from the example at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve

Comment: Well, what you did was called a function in the template that returns a Promise. The first eg on MDN assigns the return value from `Promise.resolve` to a variable and then uses `then` on it. It's different from wannadream's suggestion.

Comment: I don't see the reason to use Promise variable in your example - you can just make `async ngOnInit()`

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this short Angular issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6696), I think the accepted answer didn't quite get it right, although it's not far off. Specifically, the browser doesn't hang because it's trying to resolve a self-referential Promise.

Instead there occurs an infinite loop in Angular's change detection. Namely, with `foo() | async`, the foo() gets resolved when change detection runs, yielding a *newly created* Promise object. Next, this Promise gets fed into the async pipe('s transform function), which resolves the Promise. Because resolving a Promise can theoretically update the application state (think setting a component property in a then()-callback), change detection is run again. foo() again produces a new Promise, and the loop is complete.

SiddAjmera's fix works, because with a class property instead of a function return value, Angular (/Zone.js) can determine whether it changed since the last change detection run. I'd just adapt the fix by putting the foo-initialization right next to it's declaration, instead of splitting the two:

```
export class ComponentOrService {
  foo: Promise<string> = Promise.resolve('hello'); 
}
```