# Angular async pipe loading page forever when using getter in component

Tags: angular, asynchronous, getter, angular-standalone-components

I have created standalone component.

```js
import { AsyncPipe, CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cnn',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, AsyncPipe],
  templateUrl: './cnn.component.html',
  styleUrl: './cnn.component.css',
})
export class CnnComponent implements OnInit {
  get outputImage(): Promise<string> {
    return Promise.resolve('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Extend_Edge-Handling.png');
  }

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="output-section">
    <img
      *ngIf="outputImage | async as imageSrc"
      [src]="imageSrc"
      class="preview-image"
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

I am rendering HTML like this hoping to see image, but the page is forever loading even `curl` is not giving response as anything.

It is also showing same behaviour when i used async method instead and called like this in `HTML`

```html
<img
  *ngIf="outputImage() | async as imageSrc"
  [src]="imageSrc"
  class="preview-image"
/>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular async pipe hangs on a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53399043/angular-async-pipe-hangs-on-a-promise)

Comment: "even curl is not giving response as anything" that's a sign there's a problem with the network, not your angular code.

Comment: but as soon as I comment that `image` tag it starts working.

Comment: I am using `SSG` in Angular and maybe it is trying to call that method at build time and server is not working.